# Can I use the servletContext to get information about all the servlets

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee

1. Can I use the servletContext to get information about all the servlets that are being configured as part of the web.xml or not?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Check the Java EE API:

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html

Maybe this methods will help you.

- https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getServletRegistration(java.lang.String)
- https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getServletRegistrations()

I don't know which configurations you need specifically.